# getTransferData() in Transferhandler not working as expected for multiple dropping multiple objects in jtree

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I am trying to drag multiple rows (discontinuous ) from a jtable to a jtree. I am using a customized transferable object and a customized transferhandler.

However, I lose my objects within the import data method, as it gets lost inside the java method `getTransferData(DataFlavor df)` within class `DropTargetContext.java`.

The code is as follows:

```
public class cObjectList extends ArrayList<cObject> implements Transferable, Serializable {    

public static DataFlavor OBJECT_LIST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(cObjectList.class, "Object List");
    private DataFlavor flavors[] = { OBJECT_LIST_FLAVOR };

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {        return flavors;    }//end method  getTransferDataFlavors

@Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor.getRepresentationClass() == cObjectList .class;    }//end method isDataFlavorSupported

@Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {  return this; } else { 
throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);        }//end else
    }//end method getTransferData    
}//end class  cObjectList
```

The class cObject is serializable. The customized transfer handler is declared as an inner class within the panel that contains both tree and table. */

```
class ObjectTreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler{
/*the createTransferable method successfully creates the transfer object */
@Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        if (!canImport(support)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(cObjectList.OBJECT_LIST_FLAVOR)) {            
            cObjectList obList = null;
            try {
                Transferable t = support.getTransferable();               
                obList = (cObjectList) t.getTransferData(cObjectList.OBJECT_LIST_FLAVOR);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
                System.out.println("UnsupportedFlavor: " + ufe.getMessage());
                return false;
            } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
                new myException(ioe);
                return false;
            }

            if (obList != null && support.getComponent() instanceof myJTree) {
//do work 
            }//end if
}//end inner class ObjectTreeTransferHandler
```

The transferable object `t` has the objects in array list correctly, but when I call `t.getTransferData`, the array list comes back the `null` objects.  E.g. if three rows were chosen from the table, This calls `getTransferData`  method in `cObjectList` which returns these objects in the arraylist correctly but when it reaches `getTransferDat`a  in DropTargetContext.java  the values inside the array list return as `null` even thought the list/ object itself still shows `size =3`.

The drop mode selected for the tree is:

> treeObjectStructure.setTransferHandler(new ObjectTreeTransferHandler());  treeObjectStructure.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);

Can anyone help me figure out what I have done wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I upvote the answer above. I had the same problem and I just fixed it using what Lyle said:

```
class TransferablePanel implements Transferable {
   protected static  DataFlavor PANELFLAVOR = new DataFlavor(Object.class, "A 
   JPanel Object");//instead JPanel.class I used Object.class ****
   protected static DataFlavor[] supportedFlavors = { PANELFLAVOR };
   JPanel panel;
      public TransferablePanel(JPanel panel) {
         this.panel = panel;
      }

     @Override
     public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
         return supportedFlavors;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
         if (flavor.equals(PANELFLAVOR))
              return true;
         return false;
      } 

     @Override
     public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws 
     UnsupportedFlavorException {

if (flavor.equals(PANELFLAVOR)){
    return panel;
}
else
  throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that the first argument to the DataFlavor constructor has to be Object.class. If it's myclass.class, then I too get null returned from getTransferData, and it throws an IOException. I have no idea why this occurs. It took me several hours to determine this.